# MAME , Metal Slug, and Neo Geo

Tags: games, emulation

I am trying to play Metal Slug in mame. I have both mslug.zip and neogeo.zip, both showing up in the games list, but when I try to run Metal Slug, it says I am missing one or more required files.

Please help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about how you are running. What does the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have bad rom files.  Do a scan in mame and if the game doesn't show as playable then you have bad rom files.

Comment: Can you please add more details to this answer? How does one do a scan in MAME?